# Erro no eclipse com a linguagem android

Tags: android, android-eclipse, sdk

Bom dia, estou tentando criar um projeto Android, mais aparece essa mensagem,[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e quando vou criar o projeto que eu escolho o Blank Activity ele não criar fica travado na tela main_activity.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Me parece um problema com o plugin android do eclipse e o sdk que você baixou. Algum motivo para não usar o Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Amigo  baixe o sdk do link abaixo:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html.
Depois siga esses passos:
1- [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2- [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3- [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4- [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5- [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

6- [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyEa7.png)

7 - [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

8 - reinicie o eclipse como solicitado  e apos a reinicialização.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

9 - Informando o diretório de instalação do Android

Pronto, agora você possui um ambiente Android no seu Eclipse, e para criar um novo projeto é só ir no Menu File>New>Other... do eclipse, e selecionar a opção Android... Daí pra frente vai depender do que você pretende desenvolver.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Pronto, agora você possui um ambiente Android no seu Eclipse, e para criar um novo projeto é só ir no Menu File>New>Other... do eclipse, e selecionar a opção Android... Daí pra frente vai depender do que você pretende desenvolver.

Espero ter ajudado.